# how to remove a certain character at the end of the string in javascript

Tags: javascript, encryption

http://dren.ch/js_blowfish/

I'm experimenting with blowfishJS,
but it has a bug that makes it unusable

//lets say I want to encrypt the string "house"

```
var bf = new Blowfish('some key');

var house = "house";
var ciphertext = bf.encrypt(house);
var plaintext = bf.decrypt(ciphertext);

console.log(plaintext); //outputs house00 instead of house
```

sometimes its more than 2 zeros.

This might be helpful:

> All the strings im trying to encrypt end with "=" anyway. so it would
>   be ok to remove all the zeros at the end of the "plaintext" string
>   until the character "=" shows up.

How do I achieve this?
lets say I have the string "mystring==000" and I need to remove all the zeros at the end.
I have done my research on the "slice" function, the problem is that there is no certain "position" at the end since I can't know if 2,3 or x zeros will appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `lastIndexOf()` and `substr` from that index. for example;

```
var house = 'house=04543976439859df45345ffd43';

house.substr( 0, house.lastIndexOf('=') + 1 ); // => "house="
```

`lastIndexOf` will return the index of the last occurrence of the specified value (I do `+ 1` in this example to include the `=` character). Which we can then use with `substr` to extract all characters after that index.

Comment: thanks, but why did you use "+1" it works without it too

Comment: @user254883 I used `+1` to keep the last occurrence of `=` without doing `+1` `substr` will remove the last `=`, which i thought you wanted to keep.

Answer (score 0):

you can use regular expressions to do this, if you are sure the string ends with zeros and to trim till = use

```
plaintext.replace(/=(0)+$/g,"=");
```

Answer (score 0):

With a regex, you can remove anything after the last = regardless of being a zero.

plaintext.replace(/[^\=]+$/, "");

In plain english that is, find a maximal substring that doesn't include an '=' and it's at the end of the string and replace it for an empty string.